# Unresolved promise - Promise pending returned by then() at the beginning

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

`then()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value

> Return value
> Returns a new Promise immediately. **This new promise is always pending** when returned, regardless of the current promise's status.

`catch()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#return_value

> Return value
> Returns a new Promise. **This new promise is always pending when returned**, regardless of the current promise's status. It's eventually rejected if onRejected throws an error or returns a Promise which is itself rejected; otherwise, it's eventually fulfilled.

`finally()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally#description

> Like catch(), finally() internally calls the then method on the object upon which it was called. If onFinally is not a function, then() is called with onFinally as both arguments — which, for Promise.prototype.then(), means that no useful handler is attached. Otherwise, then() is called with two internally created functions, which behave like the following:

The MDN documentation says that the promises returned by `then()` and `catch()` are always in *pending* state at the beginning.

As I understand it, this is because those methods themselves are executed *synchronously*, but their callbacks are executed *asynchronously*.
Such callbacks are necessary to know if the promise will be *resolved* or *rejected*, and as these are executed later, the promises returned by such methods will be *unresolved*, and hence *pending* **until such callbacks are executed.**

https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-objects

> A promise is resolved if it is settled or if it has been “locked in”
> to match the state of another promise. Attempting to resolve or reject
> a resolved promise has no effect. A promise is unresolved if it is not
> resolved. **An unresolved promise is always in the pending state**. A
> resolved promise may be pending, fulfilled or rejected.

1. Is it correct as I understand it?
2. If correct as I understand it, does `finally()` apply the same?
3. Do `catch()`, `finally()` and `then()` themselves run *synchronously*?

**My 3 questions are just to understand what the pending status refers to.**

Comment: The callbacks do not determine whether the promise will be resolved or rejected. They are executed based on if the the promise is rejected or resolved.  

I don't think it is particularly useful to think whether function calls like `.then` is executed synchronously or not. Most of what they do is some type checking and registering the callbacks. So yes, they do their job immediately but the most interesting part happen inside passed the callbacks. 

I recommend reading about continuation passing style and particularly how the stack evolves in CPS

Comment: hi @sinanspd, it is necessary to know if it is synchronous or not.

Comment: Why? What user facing semantic difference does it make?

Comment: Not for the user, but for us as developers, knowing this, better decisions will be made when coding (know what goes on behind the scenes).

Comment: The user I am referring to here is the developer. It is very difficult to know and understand every single semantic decision that goes into a language. In this case, doing what a function like `then` does can result in very similar results whether sync or on resolution depending on the implementation details of course, and shouldn't impact the code you write. That's the whole idea of an interface. But of course if you are simply curious, I respect that

Comment: "*Do catch(), finally() and then() themselves run synchronously?*" - **every** function returns something synchronously. Even if it starts some asynchronous background task or registers a handler to be called later.

Comment: hi @Bergi, excellent. So, the promises returned by these 3 methods (`catch()`, `finally()` and `then()`) are *unresolved* at the beginning?

Comment: @gus yes, you understood the documentation correctly

Comment: Good. "*every function returns something synchronously.*" - Do you mean literally ANY function in JavaScript or do you just mean `catch()`/`finally()`/`then()`? @Bergi

Comment: @gus I mean what I write.