# In a promise chain, are the promises themselves created synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I asked a question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76266597/unresolved-promise-promise-pending-returned-by-then-at-the-beginning), but now new doubts have arisen that I would like to confirm.

In a *promise chaining*, are **ALL** promises created *synchronously* or are they created as `callbacks` belonging to a `then(`)/`finally()`/`catch()` are executed?

```
let promise1 = Promise.resolve('Stackoverflow');
    promise1
      .finally(() => {
        console.log('finally()');
      }) // promise 2
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Data: ' + data);
      }) // promise 3
      .catch((rejection) => {
        console.log('rejection: ' + rejection);
      }); // promise 4
```

That is, are the `promise 2`, `promise 3` and `promise 4` promises created **before** the `then()`/`finally()`/`catch()` `callbacks` are executed?

Comment: Just add logs before and after and see it yourself. See the sequence

Comment: The methods then, catch and finally exist _on promise objects_, so the promises have to be created to receive the callbacks before they can be executed.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe so, are all promises created before these callbacks are executed?

Comment: Hi @DecPK, that is a very vague answer

Comment: Again, they _have_ to be. The callbacks get passed _to the promises' methods_, and the promises then (if required) execute them.

Comment: They are created immediately. You can assign each to a different variable

Comment: Perfect @jonrsharpe, now I get it. So, `then()`/`catch()`/`finally()` methods, 1) create and return a promise *synchronously* and *immediately* and 2) "install-register" their respective `callbacks` also *synchronously* and *immediately*, right?

Comment: Yes. Promises are no magic. They can be implemented with ordinary code, and ordinary method calls have ordinary behaviour.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, we can say that a promise chaining is "divided into 2 phases", i.e. 1) the *synchronous* code is executed, in this "phase" **all** the promises of the chaining are created and 2) the *asynchronous* code is started to execute the `then()`/`finally()`/`catch()` callbacks as appropriate, right?

Comment: I would even argue that the term "promise chaining" refers only to the first phase where the promises are created and the chained method calls are happening. But "a promise chain" consists of both of these things, yes - the promises that have been created and the handler functions that link them together.

Comment: Perfect @Bergi, I needed this *point of view* (a different "approach") to fully understand it, hence the question

Answer (score 1):

In a promise chain, the methods `then`, `finally` and `catch` are immediately and synchronously called with callback functions as arguments. It's required that the promises are also immediately and synchronously created. Otherwise, the methods couldn't be called. The callback functions are called later when the promises are resolved or rejected.

`Promise.resolve('Stackoverflow')` returns a promise.

`promise1.finally` calls the method on promise `promise1` and returns a promise (synchronously)

`.then` calls a method on the previous promise and returns a new promise (synchronously)

`.catch` calls a method on the previous promise and returns a new promise (synchronously)

Each of this method gets a callback function as argument. The callback function is called later, when the promise is resolved or rejected.

Comment: "*`.then()` calls a method on*", "*`.catch()` calls a method on*" - What do you mean by that? @jabaa

Comment: @gus A method is always called on an object. `promise1.then()` is function call of the function `then` with `this` pointing to `promise1`.

Comment: I see, I thought you meant something different. In the "narration" you post, as soon as it ends, does the *asynchronous* code start? @jabaa

Comment: @gus The asynchronous code starts when something triggers it, like a button click, a timer, a network response, ... `Promise.resolve` is like a timer with 0 timeout. I enqueues an event on the event loop.

Comment: Are the `then()`/`catch()`/`finally()` methods **always** executed on the *previous* promise object? @jabaa

Comment: @gus That's how OOP works. It's not related to promises. `a.b().c().d()` is method chain. `b` is called on `a`. `c` is called on the return value of `a.b()` and `d` is called on the return value of `a.b().c()`.

Comment: Excellent @jabaa, I had never seen that approach